# justify-content-around for carousel indicators

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

Working with carousel indicators, I've got two pictures in a single slide which occupies half the width each, using bootstrap row and column. I need the carousel indicators to be at the bottom center of first image, a horizontal rule at the bottom center of both images and an anchor tag at the bottom center of second image, as shown in the pic.

[image: Expected Outcome]

Using d-flex and justify-content-around it was able to do the same for just the indicators. That is, I was able to place the indicators 01, 02 and 03 each at three centers. But unable to produce the result as expected.

```
ol.carousel-indicators.d-flex.justify-content-around  
          li.active
              a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='0') 01
          li
              a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='1') 02
          li
              a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='2') 03
```

The above code produces indicators 01, 02 and 03 each at three centers.

[image: What I get]

```
.d-flex.justify-content-around    
        ol.carousel-indicators
          li.active
              a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='0') 01
          li
              a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='1') 02
          li
              a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='2') 03
        ol.abc
            li abc
        ol.abc
            li he
```

```css
.abc {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1024;
    color: white;
}
```

And this produces unexpected results.

[image: Unexpected]

The ul here is overlapped.

The result should as of the first pic. How to resolve!

**Edit 1**

The code was updated and I got a result as below.

```
 ol.d-flex.justify-content-around.abc
        li
            ol.carousel-indicators
                li.active
                    a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='0') 01
                li
                    a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='1') 02
                li
                    a(data-target='#carouselExampleIndicators' data-slide-to='2') 03

        li abc

        li he
```

```css
.abc {

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 15;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

[image: Final]

What I'm missing here is the links are not centered as expected. While I tried replacing the list under the first li, with a sample link text it was working fine.

```
ol.d-flex.justify-content-around.abc
        li def
         /* Removed the list */
        li abc

        li he
```